# Limit of a subsequence of fractioned part

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that for all $x\in [0,1],$ the sequence of fractional parts  $(\{\sqrt{n}\})_{n\geq 1} $ contains a subsequence with the limit $x$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have $\{\sqrt{n}\}\approx x $ it is enough to have $\sqrt{n}\approx M+x$ with $M\in\mathbb{N}$ or $n \approx M^2+2M x +x^2$. So it is enough to consider a diverging sequence of (large) natural numbers $M_1,M_2,M_3,\ldots$ and define $n_k$ as the closest integer to $M_k^2+2M_k x+x^2$. The sequence of fractional parts $\{\sqrt{n_1}\},\{\sqrt{n_2}\},\{\sqrt{n_3}\},\ldots$ will converge to $x$ by the concavity of the square root function.

Answer (score 0):

Observation. Let the sequence $a_n=\{\sqrt{n}\}$, $n\in\mathbb N$, and observe that
$$
0=a_{k^2}< a_{k^2+1}<\ldots<a_{(k+1)^2-1}<1,
$$
and whenever $k^2\le m<m+1\le (k+1)^2-1,$ then
$$
0<a_{m+1}-a_m\le \sqrt{k^2+1}-k<\frac{1}{2k}.
$$
The second inequality is a consequence of the fact that 
$$
a_{m+1}-a_m=\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt{m}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt{m}}\le
\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+\sqrt{k^2}}<\frac{1}{2k}.
$$ 
Therefore, if we fix an $x\in[0,1)$, then there exists an $m\in\{k^2,k^2+1,\ldots,(k+1)^2-1\}$, such that
$$
|\{\sqrt{m}\}-x|<\frac{1}{4k}.
$$ 
This observation allows us to pick the following subsequence: From every interval of integers of the form $\{n^2,n^2+1,\ldots,(n+1)^2-1\}$, pick an integer $k_n$ satisfying
$$
|\{\sqrt{k_n}\}-x|<\frac{1}{4n}.
$$
Clearly
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{k_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\{\sqrt{k_n}\}=x.
$$